# scope value does get in link function of directive and template AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**howToUse.view.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="brif-box">
        <div class="hading cf">
            <h2>{{items.name}}</h2>
        </div>
        <p>{{items.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <my-responsive-tab info="items"></my-responsive-tab>
</div>
```

in that file **items** is my scope.

**Controller.js**

```
labcatControllers.controller('howTouseCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'LibraryService',
function($scope, $routeParams, LibraryService){
    LibraryService.getItemDetails($routeParams.lId).then(function(data){
        $scope.items = data.data;
    });
}])
```

my data is

```
{"id":"3","name":"name","demo_url":"url","description":" Lorem ipsum ","html_content":"datasssss"}
```

**directive.js**

```
 .directive('myResponsiveTab', function($sce, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            customerInfo: '=info'
        },
        templateUrl: 'view/how-to-use-my-custom-responsive-tab.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.customerInfo)
            scope.names_ = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(scope.customerInfo.demo_url);
            scope.$watch(attrs.info, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    element.find("#horizontalTab").easyResponsiveTabs({
                        type: 'default',
                        width: 'auto',
                        fit: true,
                        closed: 'accordion',
                    });                    
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**how-to-use-my-custom-responsive-tab.html**

```
<div id="horizontalTab">
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
    <li>PREVIEW</li>
    <li>HTML</li>
    <li>CSS</li>
    <li>JQUERY CODE</li>
    <li>FILES Require</li>
    <li>DOWNLOAD FILES</li>
</ul>
<div class="resp-tabs-container">
    <div>
        <iframe height="600px" width="100%" ng-src="{{names_}}"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre>
            <span class="codeIt">{{customerInfo.htmlContent}}</span>
        </pre>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre>
            <span class="codeIt">{{customerInfo.cssContent}}</span>
        </pre>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre>
            <span class="codeIt">{{customerInfo.jqueryContent}}</span>
        </pre>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre>
            <span class="codeIt">{{customerInfo.fileRequireContent}}</span>
        </pre>
    </div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

in That 
Error: scope.customerInfo is undefined.
When i console scope i see customerInfo Object that scope Object.
and When i console.log(scope.customerInfo) got undefined.
So Please tell me Where i am wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you provide the code your controller ?

Comment: Let me guess: `items` on the parent scope is being populated asynchronously?

Comment: Try with e.g. `ng-if="items"` on the element for the directive.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Plz chk update my updated question

Comment: @GregL populated asynchronously means

Comment: `$scope.items = 5; //Not async`, you are fetching the data with ajax, so it's async. (It does not get set immediately, but instead in a callback function).

Comment: @Arg0n Thanks. Bhai :)

Comment: The key thing to realise is that any code inside a `.then()` callback function will be executed some time later (i.e. _asynchronously_), even if the promise already has a value (has been resolved). The amount of time will be very small, but it will be after your directive's link function has run for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `items` on the parent controller is populated asynchronously, when the directive is *compiled* and linked, `items` will be `undefined`. Which means that `scope.customerInfo` will also be undefined.

What you can do instead is use a watch to wait until it has a value for the first time, and do everything when it does. Change your directive code to:

```
.directive('myResponsiveTab', function($sce, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            customerInfo: '=info'
        },
        templateUrl: 'view/how-to-use-my-custom-responsive-tab.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var deregWatch = scope.$watch('customerInfo', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    deregWatch(); // stop watching now we have a value
                    scope.names_ = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(scope.customerInfo.demo_url);
                    element.find("#horizontalTab").easyResponsiveTabs({
                        type: 'default',
                        width: 'auto',
                        fit: true,
                        closed: 'accordion',
                    });   
                }                 
            });
        }
    };
});
```

NB: If you need to detect changes to the `info` object, you will need to keep watching it so you can re-initialise your directive on every change. Otherwise, remove the watch to keep the digest cycle as fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I got customerInfo in directive but in template URl can not get a customerInfo Obj

Comment: @AshishMehta What do you mean by "in template URI"? Do you mean your call to `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl()`, `scope.customerInfo` is undefined? Or do you mean that you want to use a different template URL depending on the `scope.customerInfo` object?

Comment: Plz Chk my Updated Question. I want to print my customerInfo Object value in how-to-use-my-custom-responsive-tab.html

Comment: i am beginner in AngularJs. so Am i doing right way?

Answer (score 1):

By using `ng-if="items"` on the element for the directive, angular will wait to render it until you have a value in `items`, and it will not be undefined when reaching `link`.

To render the HTML do something like this in `link` or `controller` for the directive:

```
scope.myHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(customerInfo.htmlContent);
```

And in your template (something like this):

```
<span ng-bind="myHtml" class="codeIt"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks I got customerInfo in directive but in template URl can not get

Comment: Please update your question with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Plz chk my updated question.  I want to print htmlContent in how-to-use-my-custom-responsive-tab.html page

Comment: i am beginner in AngularJs. so Am i doing right way?

Comment: This does not really have to do anything with the original question. But you need to use `$sce.trustAsHtml` on `customerInfo.htmlContent` and assign it to a variable in your scope. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ok, One By one filed i have to store in scope?

Comment: For all external HTML you want to show (HTML not in your templates), you must trust it using this method.

Comment: thanks Now It's Working. It's My mistake. bind name is not same. Thanks Again